# Java - use system DNS server settings

Tags: java, dns, dnsmasq

I'm running `dnsmasq` on OSX for local offline development, and I've added `127.0.0.1` as the top DNS server in my network settings. Everything works as expected in the terminal.

My Java tests don't seem to be using the local DNS server, which is a pain as that's the main reason I needed it!

What configuration is needed for Java to pick up system DNS settings? Do I need to pass JVM system properties telling it to ise localhost?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to update system settings to use local dns.

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");
```